# SQL query result to XML - Orders, OrderDetails

Tags: mysql, sql, xml, merge, left-join

I want to get all order details of a particular orderId. My table structure is

[image]

I want the result

```
<xmldata>
  <Orders>
    <OrderID>1</OrderID> 
    <BillingAddress1>test1</BillingAddress1>
     <Total>10</Total>    
    <OrderDetails>
      <OrderDetailID>1</OrderDetailID>      
      <OrderID>1</OrderID>
      <Name>Product1</Name>    
      <Price>5</Price>  
    </OrderDetails>
    <OrderDetails>
     <OrderDetailID>2</OrderDetailID>      
      <OrderID>1</OrderID>
      <Name>Product2</Name>    
      <Price>5</Price>  
    </OrderDetails>
  </Orders>
</xmldata>
```

My SQL query returns

```
<xmldata>
  <Orders>
    <OrderID>1</OrderID> 
    <BillingAddress1>test1</BillingAddress1>
     <Total>10</Total>        
      <OrderDetailID>1</OrderDetailID>      
      <OrderID>1</OrderID>
      <Name>Product1</Name>    
      <Price>5</Price>  
    </Orders>
    <Orders>
 <OrderID>1</OrderID> 
    <BillingAddress1>test1</BillingAddress1>
     <Total>10</Total>   
     <OrderDetailID>2</OrderDetailID>      
      <OrderID>1</OrderID>
      <Name>Product2</Name>    
      <Price>5</Price>  
    </OrderDetails>
  </Orders>
</xmldata>
```

My query is

```
Select orders.*,details.*
FROM orders as orders LEFT JOIN OrderDetails as details
ON orders.orderid=details.orderid
where orders.orderid = 1
```

Comment: Hi. Please use words to say how output is a function of output & how the output differs from what is desired. Read & act on [mcve]: Can we cut & paste & run? PS [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use an image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. And never give a diagram without a legend/key.

Answer (score 0):

This query should get you the results you're looking for.

```
SELECT  Orders.*, CAST(Det AS XML)
FROM    Orders
        OUTER APPLY
        (
            SELECT * FROM OrderDetails WHERE OrderDetails.OrderID = Orders.OrderID FOR XML PATH('OrderDetails')
        ) XmlDetails(Det)
FOR XML PATH('Orders'), root('xmldata')
```

The issue with your original query was that it was denormalized XML data, as in each order detail record contained the entire order record, and therefore each XML OrderDetail element contained the metadata of its corresponding Order as well.

This query solves the issue by converting all of the order details for each order into XML before being applied to the order.

Please note that intellisense will highlight the XmlDetails derived table as returning more columns than were defined, but it does not and the query should run anyway.

Comment: sorry to post a question that why you use OUTER APPLY instead of join two table......for any performance boost?

Comment: @Mist Good question. I didn't necessarily choose OUTER APPLY for a performance boost, I chose it due to it being the only good option. If we joined the derived table instead of applying it, we would have to use xQuery in our filter condition to extract the key from the derived table, since the data has already been converted to XML. That would be uglier (and slower) than applying. If we used a CTE, we would be in the same boat, but we'd also be throwing an unnecessary CTE into the mix as well.